# What does it mean to "frank for someone"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, obscure-terms

I am reading "Sense and Sensibility" by Jane Austen. There is a statement made by Mrs. Palmers in chapter 20.

> "How charming will it be," said Charlotte, "when he is in Parliament!- won't it? How I shall laugh! It will be so ridiculous to see all his letters directed to him with an M.P. But do you know, he says he will never Frank for me? He declares he won't. Don't you, Mr Palmer?"

Comment: "Frank" as a verb:  *to mark (a piece of mail) with an official signature or sign indicating the right of the sender to free mailing*  (from [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frank).)  This is a common benefit of a government post.

Comment: https://janeaustensworld.wordpress.com/2008/10/01/an-annotated-history-of-postage-in-england/ may be informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some countries have allowed or currently allow a select group of officials to frank mail, indicating that postage has been paid, by signature, as outlined in Merriam-Webster's online definition of frank:

> a: to mark (a piece of mail) with an official signature or sign indicating the right of the sender to free mailing [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frank)

Wikipedia has an article describing the historical [Free Frank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Frank) available to British Members of Parliament in "Sense and Sensibility".